# Cannot use bash variable for tar's exclude

Tags: bash, tar

I have to build excludes for tar command dynamically. List of excludes will be wery short (if any), so much better approach is build a list of --exclude= parameters for command line than use a temporary file with --exclude-from. But using bash variable doesn't work. Look at this examle:

```
~/test$ EXCLUDES=" --exclude='./do-not-backup'"
~/test$ echo $EXCLUDES
--exclude='./do-not-backup'
~/test$ tar czf backup.tgz $EXCLUDES ./
~/test$ tar tzf backup.tgz
./
./dir1/
./dir1/file1
./do-not-backup/                       <=== wrong
./do-not-backup/nofile                 <=== wrong
./dir2/
./dir2/file2
./backup.tgz
~/test$ rm backup.tgz
~/test$ tar czf backup.tgz --exclude='./do-not-backup' ./ # Same command without bash variable
~/test$ tar tzf backup.tgz
./
./dir1/
./dir1/file1
./dir2/
./dir2/file2
./backup.tgz
```

What I miss?

Comment: Versions: same behavior observed on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (bash 4.3.48(1)-release, tar (GNU tar) 1.28 and on CentOS 7 (bash 4.2.46(2)-release, tar (GNU tar) 1.26).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to store arguments that may contain spaces is in an array. Each argument can be a separate array entry, with or without spaces.

```
$ excludes=(--exclude='./do-not-backup')
$ printf '%q\n' "${excludes[@]}"
--exclude=./do-not-backup
$ tar -czf backup.tgz "${excludes[@]}" ./
```

The single quotes here are optional, exactly as they would be if you typed the `--exclude` argument normally. As you can see, Bash parses the quotes when the array is created and they're not actually stored in the array value.